# Is SpringerLink published under Springer?

Tags: journals, conference, publishers, springer

I would like to clarify is SpringerLink published under Springer? I want to make sure its a legitimate publisher, given that plenty of fake journals are out there.

Comment: https://www.springer.com/gp/help/about-springerlink/18548

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a service of Springer. Look at the URL and the page it links to: https://link.springer.com. There is also a link (not to coin a phrase) to it from Springer's front page.

Comment: Thank you. I have a confusion there @Dr.Buffy why SpringerLink have a different url to that of Springer?

Comment: It is a service different from their standard publishing business.